# Why is $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$ a coordinate ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I saw this claim: Let $W\subset V$ be a codimension-$1$ irreducible subvariety of an $n$-dimensional normal, irreducible, affine variety $V$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$  — the coordinate ring at $W$— is a discrete valuation ring.

But why is $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$ a coordinate ring? A coordinate ring should be in the form of $k[x_1,...,x_n]/M$, but I can't see why is $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$ in that form? Also I feel confused with the definition of $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the confusion is a matter of terminology. If $W$ is a subvariety of $V$, then the coordinate ring of $V$ at $W$ isn't actually the coordinate ring of any variety, but instead it's defined to be the localization of the coordinate ring of $V$ at the prime ideal corresponding to $W$. I.e., if let $A$ be the coordinate ring of $V$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ be the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to the irreducible subvariety $W$, then $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}:=A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

This is usually called the local ring of $V$ at $W$ though, so this terminology does strike me as a bit odd.

Comment: So this is not related to the sheaf of regular functions, i.e. $\mathcal{O}(V)$?

Comment: Well, it's related, if you're familiar with sheaves, $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$ is the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_V$ at the generic point of $W$.

Comment: Just to complement the answer: if $i:W\hookrightarrow V$ is the embedding of $W$ into $V$, the sheaf of regular functions of $W$ *seen as a sheaf over $V$* is $i^*\mathcal{O}_W$, or, abusing notation, $\mathcal{O}_W$. This further shows that the notation is consistent. In this case the ring of regular functions of $W$ would again be $\mathcal{O}_W(W)$.

Comment: Is there a proof for that? can you tell any reference for a proof?